# How to Check Length / Duration of an Uploaded Video in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check the length of a video file that is being uploaded by a user?

Tried .`duration`, but this seems to only work on hosted videos that is already referenced in the DOM.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
// create the video element but don't add it to the page
var vid = document.createElement('video');
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  // create url to use as the src of the video
  var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  vid.src = fileURL;
  // wait for duration to change from NaN to the actual duration
  vid.ondurationchange = function() {
    alert(this.duration);
  };
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input">
```

Comment: This checks out - at least the 10 second video I tried it with came back with a 10.12 result. Nifty!

Answer (score -8):

Video files need to be decoded by an actual player in order to determine the duration. JavaScript can only count bytes.